# 'Calm, cool and collective' vs 'calm, cool and collected'

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between *calm, cool and collective* and *calm, cool and collected*?

What is the meaning of *collective* or *collected* when used in this way?

I checked the dictionary but still do not get it.

> collective [kəˈlɛktɪv]
>   adj
>   1. formed or assembled by collection
>   2. forming a whole or aggregate
>   3. of, done by, or characteristic of individuals acting in cooperation
>   n
>   1. (Government, Politics & Diplomacy)
>   a.  a cooperative enterprise or unit, such as a collective farm
>   b.  the members of such a cooperative
>   2. (Linguistics / Grammar) short for collective noun

Comment: the latter phrase **is a very common phrase in English.**  OK?  The first one is just a typo, or, an incorrect repeat by someone who is an idiot  :)  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Collective* means “done by a group of people”; it does not go well with *calm* and *cool*. *Collected* means “not distracted”, and it can be used with *calm* and *cool*.

Comment: +1. The correct idiom is "calm, cool and collected"; the other version is likely a mishearing since (as F'x says) it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: +1 to psmears's +1: "cool, calm, and collected" is a standard idiom; "cool, calm, and collective" is a mistake (or an intentional pun - of the specific kind which involves deliberate corruption; hmm, do we have a word for that?).

Comment: Gah! That one and "for all intensive purposes" just drive me nuts!

Comment: +1 to @Tom Anderson's +1: I hear it with the "cool, calm" word ordering, not "calm, cool."

Answer (score 7):

*Calm, cool and collective* is likely a malapropism. *Calm, cool and collected* is the actual expression. The only exception would be if the former appeared as a tagline or motto for a collective, but I find that unlikely.

Comment: Well, I wanted to suggest that we, the [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com) community, are a collective, and that we are also cool and calm... but then I got into a furious argument over what "is" is and had to rethink a bit.

Comment: +1...although IMHO you can remove the "likely".

Answer (score 0):

Calm. Cool and Collected.  A phrase used when someone is in a situation where they feel completly relaxed, totally 
composed, and are sure of themselves, or in control.Collective is a group of things, names etc. put together usually by members of a group. Most likely a typo or not hearing the word "collected" thinking it to be "collective"

Comment: Welcome to the site, but you essentially repeat the answer already given by @F'x, which you ought to upvote instead. For guidance on how to use this site, which is not a traditional discussion forum, you can consult the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).